# Is it normal that it takes a while to github to refresh the files I have pushed?

Tags: git, github, merge, push

I'm new to git and Github, so I am learning: my question is, is it normal that after pushing a file with git it takes a while to show the changes on Github and applying it to the files?

I get the notification but can't see the changes on the files.
Like this:

[image]

Comment: You pushed to another branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no: any push should be reflected within seconds.

Second, to add to Makariy's comment, check in your local repository:

```
git status
git branch -avv
```

Chances are you are not on `master` but `equis`, and your remote tracking branch would `origin/equis`. You merge it the GitHub remote branch directly on `master` through [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests).